# how to select from a table which has two different values in a column?

Tags: mysql

========================================================

## this is the sample db

I just want to get user who has both 2 and 14 in skills column. The answer should be "2"
[image]

Comment: I think this is basic *WHERE*. So, check this page out.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT seekerID
FROM mytable
WHERE skillID IN (2, 14)
GROUP BY seekerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skillID) = 2
```

`DISTINCT` keyword is necessary only in case `skillID` values can occur multiple times for a single `seekerID`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be

```
select seekerID, count(*) as cnt
from table_name
where skillid in (2,14)
group by seekerID
having cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select seekerID from table_name where skillid="2" and seekerID = ( select author from table_name where skillid="14")
```

Comment: This is not what OP want. Please read again the question carefully.

Comment: ya i just forgot about the repeated values :)